# Whats wrong with my query

Tags: javascript, caml

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsActive"/><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="SortOrder"/></OrderBy>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
```

IsActive is a yes/No where I want it to return only the Yes valuesand I want it ordered by sortOrder in ascending order

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error its just returning every single item in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrap in `"<View><Query> ... </Query></View>"`

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="IsActive"/><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="SortOrder"/></OrderBy></Query></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
```